# Call a REST and point exposed as internal load balance IP in AKS from azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-aks

I have deployed an application in Azure AKS, whose loadbalancer IP will be internal. Now i have created a logic app. From this logic app i need to call this REST end point(which is exposed via an internal loadbalancer). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to leverage Azure private endpoint and private links.

you need to have a Standard Load Balancer, and use a static IP for your kubernetes private service .

then you create a private Link on the k8s service using its internal IP on the SLB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-link-service-portal#create-a-private-link-service

after that on you App Logic app, you will need to use the private Endpoint to the private link you previous created.

After this you will need to use

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview

This allow your Azure Logic App to gain access to a Virtual Network.

Note that by granting your Logic App access to the VNET you might think that the private link isn't required, which is true, but from a security point of view, its always better to limit the access to a single endpoints VS giving access to the whole VNET